# Postgresql - select column based on condition

Tags: postgresql, case

In this query the 'Daily' in the `case` will be replaced by a variable. I am not able to make this query work. I want to have the date column being either a day, a week a month or a year based on the value of the variable. but it is giving me various errors..

- CASE types date and double precison cannot be matched
- syntax error near "as"

what am I doing wrong?

```
select 
case 'Daily' 
    when 'Daily' then DATE(to_timestamp(e.startts)) as "Date",
    when 'Weekly' then DATE_PART('week',to_timestamp(e.startts)) as "Date",
    when 'Monthly' then to_char(to_timestamp(e.startts), 'mm/yyyy') as "Date",
    when 'Yearly' then to_char(to_timestamp(e.startts), 'yyyy') as "Date",
end
sum(e.checked)
from entries e
WHERE
e.startts >= date_part('epoch', '2020-10-01T15:01:50.859Z'::timestamp)::int8
and e.stopts <  date_part('epoch', '2021-11-08T15:01:50.859Z'::timestamp)::int8
group by "Date"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE ... END` is an expression. An expression must have a well-defined data type, so PostgreSQL makes sure that the expressions in the `THEN` clause have the same data type (or at least compatible ones).

You would need a type cast, probably to `text`, in the first two branches:

```
... THEN CAST (date(to_timestamp(e.startts)) AS text)
```

But it would be much better to use `to_char` in all branches – there are format codes for everything you need.

An expression can have no alias, only an entry in the `SELECT` or `FROM` list can. So you need to append `AS "Date"` at the end of the `CASE ... END` expression, not somewhere in the middle.